# Relationship between energy bands, DOS and magnetic ordering

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory

I'm struggling to understand whether we can tell if a system will have magnetic ordering (e.g. antiferromagnetic) based on the aspect of an energy bands plot or/and the form of the DOS.

My thought at first was that every insulator should have magnetic ordering (e.g. Mott insulator) and all metallic materials should be otherwise (quote from Mahan's book "Many Particle Physics" pg 411: "[...] the usual metallic phase, with no magnetic ordering, is called paramagnetic [...]").

However, this is not true, and a good example is graphene nanoribbons. Due to the edge states in this system, a large DOS exists at the Fermi level, hence the system is metallic. However, the system has magnetic ordering (why?) of type ferrimagnetic (see http://journals.jps.jp/doi/abs/10.1143/JPSJ.65.1920 ).

The question is: can we predict the magnetic ordering of a system from looking at the energy bands and/or DOS? If not, how can we predict the existence of such magnetic orderings?

Comment: Trivial answer (which is not probably what you are looking for, but it answers your question nevertheless): If the DOS or energy bands are spin-resolved, you can immediately see that there is magnetic ordering, because you will see that dos/bands for spin channels are different. For some anti-ferromagnetic compounds, which have translation+spin-flip symmetry, this does not work, and you have to look at LDOS. (There might also be some other non-trivial cases).

Comment: I believe you would need to consider the interactions too.

Comment: Well the DOS in a system does not take into account interactions, and yet it could indicate presence of magnetic ordering as in the paper posted